# python geopy returns NoneType object

Tags: location, coordinates, locate, geopy

I somehow can't iterate through the geolocator.reverse() function in geopy. It always runs into giving me NoneType objects.

Single requests like this work perfectly fine:

```
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("52.4286, 13.3556")
plz = location.address,
print(type(plz[0]))
print(plz[0])
```

I get: `<type 'unicode'>
9, Mudrastraße, Lankwitz, Steglitz-Zehlendorf, Berlin, 12249, Deutschland`
However if I try to iterate with a list of Nord and Ost coordinates, which are `<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>` objects with this code:

```
p = "\"{0}, {1}\"".format(Nord2, Ost2)
print(p)

try:        
    location = geolocator.reverse(p, timeout=10)
except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
    print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s"%(my_address, e.msg))
    plz = location.address,
    print(type(plz[0]))
    print(plz[0])
```

I get this: `"52.4955, 13.2694"
<type 'NoneType'>
None`

Does anyone knows a way out of this? do I still somehow have to change the object type of p? Or whats the matter with this?

Comment: of course p is a string! after `p = "\"{0}, {1}\"".format(Nord2, Ost2)`

Comment: Why are you putting `\"` quote literals in your string?

Comment: Thats apparently whats needed according to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy `>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
>>> print(location.address)`

Comment: but also removing quote literals still just gives me a NoneType object